# Is it accurate to call Webpack and/or Babel a compiler?

Tags: javascript, terminology

I'm curious about the terminology for compilers with JavaScript.

When you're writing about or describing technologies like Webpack *(bundles multiple files into one, and performs optimization)* and Babel *(converts ES6 to an older version of JavaScript)*, would compiler be the best word to describe these?

Comment: Babel is a *transpiler,* which is just a compiler where the source and target languages are both high-level languages.  Webpack is just... Webpack.  Portions of Webpack *might* be considered to perform the function of a compiler, which is to translate one programming language into another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think so.

A compiler parses input (text) in one language and outputs code in another language.  It generally requires a parser, some intermediate representation, and a (code) generator.  There may be optimization phases that analyze the intermediate representation for possible efficiency improvements.  In some sense a compiler is a big de-serializer and serializer coupled together by an intermediate data structure.

A [transpiler aka source-to-source compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) is a compiler.

---

(Please note that source-to-source is a 100% misnomer, it really should be text-to-text, as not all text is *source* — especially compiler output that is text!  Source is only that which must be protected because it cannot be regenerated.)